# Why might ffprobe -show_format disagree with -show_data duration?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, ffprobe

For the purposes for re-encoding a video, I am probing an mp4 (h264/aac) file. I'm wondering why there a discrepancy between the video [STREAM]'s reported duration `duration=6.500000` (while the audio's duration is 6.54, the video's duration should be the target) and the duration in provided by the -show_data and -show_format options `duration=6.466667` may occur as seen in the following output.

```
~/workspace/ (master):ffprobe -show_format -show_streams -show_data -of json original.mp4
ffprobe version 2.2.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  3 2014 06:51:16 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.2.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libavresample   1.  2.  0 /  1.  2.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
{
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'original.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2014-06-22 19:43:39
  Duration: 00:00:06.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1164 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 480x480, 1087 kb/s, 27.23 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-22 19:43:39
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-22 19:43:39
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/1200",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 480,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "0:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "0:1",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 30,
            "r_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "354/13",
            "time_base": "1/600",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 3900,
            "duration": "6.500000",
            "bit_rate": "1087856",
            "nb_frames": "177",
            "extradata": "\n00000000: 014d 001e ffe1 000e 674d 001e ab60 f07b  .M......gM...`.{\n00000010: 4d40 4041 8080 0100 0428 ee17 0c         M@@A.....(...\n",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "2014-06-22 19:43:39",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "Core Media Video"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/44100",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
            "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "44100",
            "channels": 1,
            "channel_layout": "mono",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/44100",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 288768,
            "duration": "6.548027",
            "bit_rate": "64599",
            "nb_frames": "282",
            "extradata": "\n00000000: 1208                                     ..\n",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "2014-06-22 19:43:39",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "Core Media Audio"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "original.mp4",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "6.466667",
        "size": "941468",
        "bit_rate": "1164702",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "mp42",
            "minor_version": "1",
            "compatible_brands": "mp41mp42isom",
            "creation_time": "2014-06-22 19:43:39"
        }
    }
}
```